# Why does my loop only work correctly through the first iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

EDIT: The reason why this is wrong is because I keep iterating over the first `submitted_answer` even after it's been matched to an `answer`. I still don't know how to fix this, though.

This is showing which of the user's answers in a multiple choice quiz is correct or wrong. `@quiz` here refers to the user model Quiz which `has_many Questions which`has_many`Answers. @submitted_quiz refers to the model`SubmittedQuiz`, which`has_manysubmitted_answers`.  My plan is to compare`submitted_answers`to the actual answers (found by`@quiz.question.answer), and show the user which answers they got incorrect or correct. Here's the code:

```
  <% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li> <%= question.content  %> </li>


    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <% @submitted_quiz.submitted_answers.each do |submitted_answer| %>

    <% if(submitted_answer.content == answer.content && submitted_answer.question.id == answer.question.id && submitted_answer.got_correct) %>
    <li><span class ='correct-answer'><%= answer.content %> CORRECT </span></li>
    <% break %>

    <% elsif(submitted_answer.content == answer.content && submitted_answer.question.id == answer.question.id && submitted_answer.got_incorrect) %>
    <li><span class ='incorrect-answer'><%= answer.content %> INCORRECT</span></li>
    <% break %>

    <% else %>
    <li><span class ='normal-answer'> <%= answer.content %> NORMAL</span></li>
    <% break %>

    <% end #  if statement%>

    <% end # submitted_answers.each do%>

    <% end # question.answers.each do |answer|%>

    <% end # @quiz.questions.each do %>
</ol>
```

This works great for the first `question` of `quiz.questions`. Correct answers are marked correctly and incorrect answers are marked correctly. However, on the second (and every question after that) nothing is marked correct or incorrect. For example, if the normal output should be (user got both questions right):

```
Q1
Answer 1 CORRECT
Answer 2 NORMAL
Answer 3 NORMAL
Answer 4 NORMAL
Q2
Answer 1 CORRECT 
Answer 2 NORMAL
Answer 3 NORMAL
Answer 4 NORMAL
```

The actual output will be:

```
Q1
Answer 1 CORRECT
Answer 2 NORMAL
Answer 3 NORMAL
Answer 4 NORMAL
Q2
Answer 1 NORMAL  
Answer 2 NORMAL
Answer 3 NORMAL
Answer 4 NORMAL
```

If I remove the `else` statement, the output becomes what I expect:

```
Q1
Answer 1 CORRECT

Q2
Answer 1 CORRECT.
```

But then I won't be able to show all the answers in each question.

I've been stuck on this for a day now. Why does this happen?

Comment: I think each question should have one correct_answer and has many submitted_answer.

Comment: `correct_answer` is not a model -- just an row under `submitted_answer`. If I remove the `else` statement everything works as expected (obviously though you won't show any other answers other than the ones the user marked, so a problem still remains.)

Comment: correct_answer doesn't have to be a model obviously, it could be a text field in the question table, it could be an answer from answer model with a different foreign key. It just doesn't make sense to me to literate over question.answers and then inside iterate over submitted answer

Comment: you misunderstand, which is my fault since I messed it up. `correct_answer` is an attribute of `answer`. `submitted_answer` is something completely different -- I use it to store whatever the user checks off. So rephrasing your first comment, each question has many `answers`, only one of which has the `correct_answer` attribute set to `true`. This definitely isn't a model problem regardless because I checked the database myself and everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li> <%= question.content %> </li>

  # In submitted quiz table, every submission must store question and answer ids.
  <% submitted_answer = @submitted_quiz.submitted_answers.find_by(question_id: question.id) %>

  # Every question record stores answer ids along with correct_answer id.
  <% correct_answer_id = question.correct_answer %>

  <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <% if answer.id == submitted_answer.answer_id && answer.id == correct_answer_id %>
      <li><span class ='correct-answer'><%= answer.content %> CORRECT </span></li>
    <% elsif answer.id == submitted_answer.answer_id && answer.id != correct_answer_id %>
      <li><span class ='incorrect-answer'><%= answer.content %> INCORRECT</span></li>
    <% else %>
      <li><span class ='normal-answer'> <%= answer.content %> NORMAL</span></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```